# Change components properties in large scale

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I have a reasonable amount of components attached to a window. I want to change some properties of these components when a button is pressed.
But do this in one component at a time is a boring job and will involve many lines of code.
It is possible to make a component to listen the other component signal to perform a task when the signal is released?
That is, something like the observer pattern.
If this is not possible. What would be the best way to do a mass change of these components?

Example:

[image]

[Code UI](https://paste.gnome.org/psstffmkw)

And if I want to reset all the other components to the initial state when the "Reset" button is triggered?
Create a handler to the button signal and change the components (Entries, Switches, CheckBose, ...) one at a time is very tiring

Comment: Why not just iterate over all the widgets and reset them? `for entry in [entry1, entry2, entry3, ...]: entry.set_text('')` `for checkbutton in [checkbutton1, ...]: checkbutton.set_active(False)` etc. Or if that's still too much effort, why not reload the entire thing from your xml file?

Comment: This is an alternative.
I could also use the `GtkBuilder.get_objects()` method and make `list comprehension` and get only the components the kind I want.
But I'm curious about your last suggestion. How this could be done within the XML?

Comment: I didn't mean to do anything within the XML. I'm saying you could `destroy()` the widgets and use another `Gtk.Builder` to re-create them.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you wanted but...

You are probably optimizing in the wrong place. The window in your example takes about 6 lines of very straight-forward code to 'reset'. This is insignificant compared to the benefits of the solution:

- the code is very easy to understand later on
- it's also easy to modify later on (when e.g. a default value changes)

These are far more important things than the two minutes you spend on writing the code originally -- and this is unlikely to change even if you make the form more complex (although I would question the basic design if you end up with a screen full of GtkEntries).